# scrapy callback doesnt work in function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

When executing the first **yield** it will not go into the function **parse_url** and when executing the second **yield** it will not go back the function **parse** and it just end. During the whole process, there are no exceptions. I don't know how to deal with this problem, I need help.

```
import scrapy
import re
from crawlurl.items import CrawlurlItem

class HouseurlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'houseurl'
    allowed_domains = ['qhd.58.com/ershoufang/']
    start_urls = ['http://qhd.58.com/ershoufang//']
    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.221 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-info"]/h2[@class="title"]/a/@href').extract()
        next_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').extract()

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,headers=self.header,callback=self.parse_url)

        if next_url:
            next_url = next_url[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url,headers=self.header,callback=self.parse)

    def parse_url(self,response):
        item = CrawlurlItem()
        url_obj = re.search('(http://qhd.58.com/ershoufang/\d+x.shtml).*',response.url)
        url = url_obj.group(1)
        item['url'] = url
        yield item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully looked at the logs then you might have noticed that `scrapy` filtered offsite domain requests. This means when `scrapy` tried to ping `short.58.com` and `jxjump.58.com`, it did not follow through. You can add those domains to the `allowed_domains` filter in your Spider class and you will see the requests being sent.

Replace:

```
allowed_domains = ['qhd.58.com/ershoufang/']
```

With:

```
allowed_domains = ['qhd.58.com', 'short.58.com', 'jxjump.58.com']
```

And it should work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `allowed_domains` clause. It should contain only domains, without paths. So your `qhd.58.com/ershoufang/` item is not being recognized. As a result, *all* URLs you yield (except for `start_urls`) are actually filtered out which is reflected in logs:

```
2017-06-24 14:05:09 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'qhd.58.com': <GET http://qhd.58.com/ershoufang/30456249766826x.shtml>
```

This is definitely not what you want. You can fix this by putting just a domain in `allowed_domains` and filtering unwanted URLs somewhere else, e.g. before `yield`ing them:

```
allowed_domains = ['qhd.58.com']
...
for url in urls:
    if 'qhd.58.com/ershoufang/' in url:
        yield response.follow(url, self.parse_url, headers=self.header)
...
```

Also it is usually better to use `response.follow()` instead of `scrapy.Request()` because the former one supports relative URLs.